# Unable to push files in git repository

Tags: github

I am trying to push my files using git bash to online git repository using this command.

```
$ git push -u origin master https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git
```

But after using it i am getting this error

> fatal: invalid refspec 'https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git'

How can I solve this problem? I am a newbie when using github so please elaborate what you guys are telling me to do.
[image]

Comment: Is it a private repository? As https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test gives a 404?

Comment: yes ,let me make it public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrepositorygt)

```
git push <repository> [<refspec>…]
```

> The "remote" repository that is destination of a push operation.
>   **This parameter can be either a URL** (see the section [GIT URLS](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#URLS) below) or the name of a remote (see the section REMOTES below).

So yes, `git push` *can* take a URL

But the order is important:

- where you push (the URL or remote name)
- what you push

In your case:

```
git push -u origin master 

git push -u https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git master
```

But not both `origin` and `https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git`

The first form is preferred. Once that first command is working, a simple `git push` will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

`git push` doesn't take a URL. Instead it takes the name of a remote repository that you've previously set up, that's `origin`, and a branch to push. `origin` is automatically set up when you `git clone` a repository.

If you run `git remote -v` you should see something like this:

```
origin  https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git (push)
```

If you see some other URL, use `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git` to make `origin` point at that URL.

Then `git push origin master` says to push your `master` branch to the `master` branch on the repository identified by `origin` which is `https://github.com/SMAmmar/git-test.git`.

See also

- [Working With Remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)
- [Managing Remote Repositories](https://help.github.com/en/articles/managing-remote-repositories)